Using the example of Object detection with Model Garden on my own data set
I am trying to use the example on this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfmodels/vision/object_detection.
I replaced the customized data with my own zip dataset file created on roboflow and then changed the Create category index dictionary to match with my own dataset.
But the last step of "visualize predictions" always shows nothing. I even tried to decrease min_score_thresh, but it still didn't help.
Can anyone help on what I have missed?
Thanks a lot!
